# How to insert data into a table in which the tablename is a php variable that changes based on the button click?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to insert the data only to the current table (which are already created by the admin and are empty) and not to all the tables when the 'Apply' button is clicked. But this code inserts the same data to all the tables. Here is my code. How to correct this?

```
<?php
//Setting up Database connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bhc-tpd-db");
//Check Connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "<script>alert('Database connection failed')</script>";
}

//Query to fetch records from the table
$query="SELECT * FROM event";
//Execute the query and store the result set
if ($result = $con->query($query))
{
    //output data of each row
    $row="";
    global $cname;

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $cname=$row['cname'];
    echo "<center><table>
    <tr><th>Company Name</th><td>".$cname."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Job Title</th><td>".$row["job_title"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Job Description</th><td>".$row["job_desc"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Preferred Candidates</th><td>".$row["candidates"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Eligibility</th><td>".$row["eligibility"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Salary Package/CTC</th><td>".$row["salary"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Job Location</th><td>".$row["job_location"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Selection Process</th><td>".$row["sel_procs"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Venue</th><td>".$row["venue"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Event Date</th><td>".$row["event_date"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Event Time</th><td>".$row["event_time"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Comment</th><td>".$row["comment"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align:right;'><button name='apply'>Apply</button></td></tr>
    </table></center>";

    echo "<hr>";

    if (isset($_POST['apply']))
    {
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];

    //$tablename[$row]=$row["cname"];
    $query="INSERT INTO $cname SELECT * FROM stu_reg WHERE email='$username' IF NOT EXISTS";
        if ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<script>alert('".$cname ." Registered successfully');</script>";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "<script>alert('".$cname ." ERROR / Already Registered');</script>";
        }
    }
    }//while ending
}   

else
{
echo "0 events";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is some  html around this part of the script.
Since you have multiple buttons then with the same name ('apply'), it will find an $POST['apply'] for all rows and that explains your current behaviour.
If you put a value in each button:

```
<button name='apply' value='$cname'>...</button>
```

And you do something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['apply']) && $_POST['apply'] == $cname)
```

It will probably work correctly.
Don't forget to escape all user input to protect yourself from SQL-injection.
Also escape the $cname, in case there are apostrophes in the name.

In the mysql query, you should put the table name in backticks like:

```
INSERT INTO `$cname`
```

Because is $cname is a command or property from mysql (like USER or DATA or TABLE) your script will otherwise crash.

Comment: Velthius : Thank you so much for this solution. This one works for me. But unfortunately, it lands me in another error which is as follows: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BHC-TPD\view_events.php on line 95"

Comment: You never execute your INSERT query.  After the    $query="INSERT INTO    line you should have a line like:
    if ($result = $con->query($query)){

    //last part with registred/already registred

    }